# Representing the image data for recognition

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

So I am working on a project for school and what we are trying to do is to teach a neural network to recognize buildings from non-buildings. The problem I am having right now is representing the data in a form, that would be "readable" by the classifier function.

The training data is a bunch of pictures + .wkt file with coordinates of buildings on a picture. So far we have been able to rescale the polygons, but kinda got stuck there.

Can you give any hints or ideas of how to bring this all to an appropriate form?

**Edit**: I do not need the code written for me,  a link to an article on a similar subject or a book is more of stuff I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. What code have you already tried? Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what framework you are using, but I will give an answer for caffe.

Your problem is very close to detecting objects within an image. You have full images with object (building in your case) bounding boxes.

The easiest way of doing this is through a python data layer which reads an image and a file with stored coordinates for that image and feeds that into your network. A tutorial on how to use it can be found here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/python-layer
To accelerate the process you may want to store image, coordinate pairs in your custom lmdb database.

Finally a good working example with complete caffe implementation can be found within Faster-RCNN library here: https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn/
You should check roi_pooling_layer.cpp in their custom caffe branch and roi_data_layer on how the data is fed into the network.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into that.